# Changing images on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change images on hover,i put the default image at size 108x100 and the image that was suppose to change into on hover is at size 161x143 but when i hover image does change but  instead of enlarge it gets even smaller.

Here is my html(bootstrap) code...

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
    <div class="well" style="margin-bottom:0px;background-color:black;">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div  class="row" style="margin-left:8.3333%">
                        <div  class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1  col-md-1  col-lg-1">
                            <img id="graficki-dizajn" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1  col-md-1  col-lg-1">
                            <img id="stampa-svih-formata" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1  col-md-1  col-lg-1">
                            <img id="web-dizajn" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                            <img id="kreativno-pisanje" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
                            <img id="pr" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
                            <img id="izrada-tv-i-radio-reklama" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
                            <img id="media-buying" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
                            <img id="3d-projektovanje" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
                            <img id="promocije-i-manifestacije" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
                            <img id="prevod-tekstova" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
                            <img id="prikupljanje-i-izrada-dokumenata-za-potrebe-firme" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/108x100" >
                        </div>




                    </div>
                </div>




            </div>


        </div><!-- End Carousel -->
    </div><!-- End Well -->
</div>
```

My jquery for hover change...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#graficki-dizajn").hover(function() {

    $("#graficki-dizajn").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");

        }, function() {

    $("#graficki-dizajn").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");



});

$("#stampa-svih-formata").hover(function() {

    $("#stampa-svih-formata").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");

        }, function() {

    $("#stampa-svih-formata").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");



});

$("#web-dizajn").hover(function() {

    $("#web-dizajn").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");

        }, function() {

    $("#web-dizajn").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");



});

$("#kreativno-pisanje").hover(function() {

    $("#kreativno-pisanje").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");

        }, function() {

    $("#kreativno-pisanje").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");



});

$("#pr").hover(function() {

    $("#pr").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");

        }, function() {

    $("#pr").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");



});


$("#izrada-tv-i-radio-reklama").hover(function() {

    $("#izrada-tv-i-radio-reklama").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");

        }, function() {

    $("#izrada-tv-i-radio-reklama").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");



});

$("#media-buying").hover(function() {

    $("#media-buying").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");
        }, function() {

    $("#media-buying").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");
});

$("#3d-projektovanje").hover(function() {

    $("#3d-projektovanje").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");
        }, function() {

    $("#3d-projektovanje").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");
});

$("#promocije-i-manifestacije").hover(function() {

    $("#promocije-i-manifestacije").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");
        }, function() {

    $("#promocije-i-manifestacije").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");
});



$("#prevod-tekstova").hover(function() {

    $("#prevod-tekstova").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");
        }, function() {

    $("#prevod-tekstova").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");
});

$("#prikupljanje-i-izrada-dokumenata-za-potrebe-firme").hover(function() {

    $("#prikupljanje-i-izrada-dokumenata-za-potrebe-firme").attr("src","http://placehold.it/161x143");
        }, function() {

    $("#prikupljanje-i-izrada-dokumenata-za-potrebe-firme").attr("src","http://placehold.it/108x100");
});


 });
```

And jsfiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/s2b47/

I am not enlarging the same image,the two images are different by appearance and by resolution...How can i achieve enlarge effect that i want?Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `.img responsive` class is shrinking your layout to keep it responsive. You can override it , though, but I'm not sure you'll like the result much:

**CSS**

```
.img-responsive {

        max-width: 90%;

    }

    .img-responsive:hover {

        max-width: 100%;

    }


       .well {

max-height: 60px;
   }
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s2b47/2//)**

I suggest you start out again, maybe use more fixed values of your container navbar so that it won't move. Also, the respnsiveness forces the images to be quite less than their actual size and on some displays people will most likely be unable to recognize what's depicted on the image.

Comment: this is close to the thing that i want,but now the whole container resizes on hover?How can i fix that problem?

Comment: As I said, you might need more fixed values. In this case - a fixed container height. Just put in 'max-height: 60px;' in your well. Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2b47/2/)**

Comment: Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `.img-responsive` class on your images, which means they will take up 100% of the space available (up to their own max. width). So if the available space is 100px, your original image is 120px natively, it will take up 100px. When you then change its `src` to another, bigger image, it will still just take up 100px.

Comment: As a sidenote: you should refactor your code so you don't have one hover event function per image, but one for all images at once and add the hover src as a `data-hover-src` attribute that you then read out. (see example: http://jsfiddle.net/aH9vf/)

Comment: You can edit your answer and put that content in there.