# How to shuffle images at regular time intervals while hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onhover

After researching:
[Changing images on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196757/changing-images-on-hover)
is about the closest found to something that helped me. It didn't help much. I don't have any formal web experience. So, anyone who does, it would be beyond appreciated to a) fix my issue, but b) to actually know why this thing is not shuffling images..

So this is where I'm at in my HTML:

```
<div class="navBar" id="myNavBar">    
    <ul id="navOptions">

        <li> <img id="logo" 
              src="images/logo.png" 
              onmouseover="hoverFunction(this);" ></li>

        <li class="active"><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function hoverFunction(element) {
    var images = ["images/logo.png",
                  "images/logo_2.png",
                  "images/logo_3.png",
                  "images/logo_4.png",
                  "images/logo.png"];

    for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++){
        $(element).attr("src",images[i]);
    }
    //element.setAttribute('src', 'images/logo_2.png');
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Looks like you are changing the image from the first one through all the others and back to the first as fast as possible. This will be fast enough such that you will not perceive the change (start and end on the same image).

Comment: Good analysis. I figured something like that was going on. Or something was wrong with the way I was accessing it in the function. I guess the function I am like for is a 'While on hover do this' type of function. Know of anything like that?

Comment: BTW: If an answer was good/helpful, please upvote that answer. If an answer solved your problem, please accept it.  If it was both helpful and solved your problem, please do both. This is how such things are indicated on StackExchange/stackoverflow. You should do this on all your questions. You should also upvote any questions or answers you read which you find to be good, even if they are not on your own questions.

Comment: @Makyen awesome, I would upvote them if my reputation permitted so.  I think I need to be a 15, I'm currently an 11. But everyone who commented had some very good feedback, thought provoking at the very least.

Comment: @Mayken if you would be so kind as to thumb up my question it would allow me more opportunity in the future to thank thoughtful and helpful individuals like yourself with thumbs up :)

Comment: Done. I should have done that after editing your question yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

What you appear to want is to, while the `<img>` is hovered, periodically change the image. Generally, this will be done by starting an interval timer, using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), when you receive the [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) event. The function that would be called each time the interval fires changes to the next image. When you receive the [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) event, you would then stop the interval timer, using [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

The following code will cycle through images while the mouse hovers over the `<div>`:

```js
var images = ["http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a",
              "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.png?v=93426798a1d4",
              "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.png?v=6c3100d858bb",
              "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/su/su-icon.png?v=0ad5b7a83e49"
];
var curImageIndex = 0; // 0 is displayed by default
var intervalId; //Remember the ID of the interval so we can stop it later.

function startImageCycle(el){
    cycleImage(el); //Cycle the image now so feels responsive. Remove if not wanted.
    intervalId = setInterval(cycleImage,1000,el); //Change image every 1000ms (1s)
}
function stopImageCycle(el){
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
function cycleImage(element){
    curImageIndex++;
    if(curImageIndex >= images.length) {
        curImageIndex = 0;
    }
    $(element).attr("src", images[curImageIndex]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navBar" id="myNavBar">
      <ul id="navOptions">
        <li>
          <img id="logo" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"
               onmouseenter="startImageCycle(this);" onmouseout="stopImageCycle(this);"
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="default.asp">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Beyond helpful, truly appreciated mate.

Comment: Very clean and understandable too, many props. Also cool to see the setInterval function takes a function (which increments and sets the image), a time, and an img object in html.

Comment: @bmc, Thanks. I'm happy to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use counter

```
var counter=1;
function hoverFunction(element) {
   counter++
    var images = ["http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg",
              "http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg",
              "http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg",
              "http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg",
              "http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg"];

   $(element).attr("src",images[counter]);
  if(counter ==5){
    counter=1;
  }

//element.setAttribute('src', 'images/logo_2.png');
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jAZogO

option2:updated codepen

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WxYwvK

Comment: This is a great response, but my only issue is that it isn't like a stream of images shuffling, it only shuffles once as a I hover. I wanted it to shuffle through all of them continually until it's not hovered on anymore.

Comment: That's a really helpful tool posting that on codepen for me; thank you so much. It worked great too, only 1 catch: I couldn't stop it from over shuffling!! What I learned from your solution is the 2nd argument to the JQuery with the 3000ms! Thanks mate!

Comment: @bmc updated codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WxYwvK  check it once now :)

Comment: @bmc, on hover it starts and stops on unhover